# Add dynamically websocket connection via REST endpoint in spring boot application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, websocket

I have implemented WebSocket mechanism in spring boot application.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocket
public class WebSocketConfiguration implements WebSocketConfigurer {

    private String webSockerClientUri;
    private WebSocketHandlerRegistry webSocketHandlerRegistry;
    private  WebSocketHandler webSocketHandler;

    @Override
    public void registerWebSocketHandlers(WebSocketHandlerRegistry webSocketHandlerRegistry) {
        this.webSocketHandlerRegistry = webSocketHandlerRegistry;
        this.webSocketHandler = registerWebSocketHandler();
        this.webSocketHandlerRegistry.addHandler(this.webSocketHandler, "/test");
    }

    public WebSocketHandler registerWebSocketHandler(){
        return new WebSocketHandler();
    }

    public WebSocketHandlerRegistry getWebSocketHandlerRegistry() {
        return webSocketHandlerRegistry;
    }

    public WebSocketHandler getWebSocketHandler() {
        return webSocketHandler;
    }
}
```

During startup appp WebSocketHandlerMapping detect registration of Websocket connection `"/test"`. I would like to do the same action in REST endpoint like this.

```
@PostMapping("/{uri}")
public ResponseEntity register(@PathVariable("uri") String uri){
    if (uri != null){
        this.webSocketConfiguration.getWebSocketHandlerRegistry().addHandler(webSocketConfiguration.getWebSocketHandler(), "/" + uri);
        return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.OK);
    }
    else {
        return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
    }
}
```

Uri is added into WebSocketHandlerRegistry however mechanism WebSocketHandlerMapping doesn't detect that fact, because it is not startup state of app. How can I solve this problem?